# Closure and Deletion: Why do some conductors quiver their body or grimace?

Tags: discussion

https://music.stackexchange.com/q/69979/26407 was closed by 2 users and 1 moderator. Doesn' tit  involve music practice and performance? On May 5 18, [it was automatically deleted](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/69979/26407). Please undelete?

Comment: I have edited your question a bit to make it more relevant and pointed. I think it's an interesting and perhaps important question, and should be re-opened.

Comment: @Stinkfoot Thank you!

Comment: NP - One more vote to go. You ask some off-beat questions (I suppose that is reflected in your handle) but they are interesting, and  most of them deserve good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I voted to close this question but now I'm voting to re-open it.

IMO it's a reasonable question - we see very very often that conductors (and also musicians) express themselves facially and bodily in certain peculiar ways during a performance - clearly that has something to do their performance and it is a matter of interest and perhaps of importance: If grimacing somehow helps you perform better, than being embarrassed to do so in front of an audience might hinder your performance, and perhaps allowing yourself to grimace, etc will improve your performance: Playing music can be a highly emotional experience, that can and should inspire your entire body.

---

As for @DoktorMayhem's contention

> It's like asking why some stick their tongue out during difficult
>   passages...

IMO that's also a valid question.

[image]
**Jimi Hendrix**

[image]
**Elvin Jones**

[image]
**Isaac Perlman**

Clearly, something is going on here.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Care to vote for undeletion please?

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal - already did...

Answer (score 2):

Not in any way that is on topic here, no. I would also suggest it would be Too Broad and Opinion Based.

It's like asking why some stick their tongue out during difficult passages...

Answer (score 1):

I thought this was a somewhat interesting question - I also thought of BB King's gurning - and as Dr M says, other facial contortions are also often seen!

But this is a site for questions about how to perform and analyse music - so you need to ask the question in a way that engages people from that point of view. If you were to make it clear that you want to talk about ways to display passion that engage the audience, etc... that might be more on-topic here. Again, it comes back to the point I made in another recent meta answer that you seem to be something of a specialist at questions that are very borderline; If it's your aim to get them answered, do the work to make your questions *good* questions, according to the standards of the site.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Can you please edit my question, based on the recommendations in your last para.?

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal I often do try to tweak people's questions to get them 'the right side of the line' - but in this case I think it would have to be rather a large change, so you as the OP are probably in a better position to know exactly what angle would be interesting to you!

Comment: It *might* be on-topic, I'm not sure I agree with Mayhem, Phd. in this case, but the answer is likely to be different for every musician, so I do agree it's some combination of too broad and opinion based. Also arguably not helpful.

Comment: @topomorto Can you please try anyways? You've conveyed ideas better than I have on this website.

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal I feel that partly because of this meta question, any attempt to edit and re-open would be under great scrutiny and I'm not sure I could handle the emotional pressure. If there's a question along these lines that you want to ask but it's not yet wording itself in your mind in a way that fits on the site, I honestly think that the best thing is just to keep sleeping on it until it does.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Care to vote for undeletion please?