# Advice for my 30-day suspension for only 2 answers?

Tags: discussion

On Jun 10 2018, I was suspended for 30 days for posting 2 answers. The previous time that I posted anything was Apr 2 2018.  Yet  I think I could've solved any difficulties without  a suspension?

#### [1st Answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/71772/26407)

I acknowledge that I oughtn't just reference Youtube; that was my mistake. I didn't transcribe it as watching Carter speak felt more educational.  But I offered to transcribe immediately after a moderator deleted it, yet I wasn't permitted to:

> Once your suspension is finished, posting a full answer including a link to the Elliot Carter interview would be welcome.

As this post could've been corrected straightaway, the suspension was truly based on 1 answer.

#### [2nd Answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/71552/26407)

The quotes from Reddit do answer "Why isn't there a classical composer like Beethoven, Chopin or Mozart today?". I'd surmise that the downvotes are due to the anonymity of the authors? If yes, then I truly didn't know that anonymous authors can't be quoted here.

#### Decision itself

I quote the relevant parts of messages from moderators.

> We see that your behavior is showing the same signs as it has on other sites. Posting types of questions you have been told not to post, such as link only answers, off topic questions, and then challenging every deletion or block on meta.
>
> You have so far done the same thing on a few sites, starting off with the same minor issues but escalating over time to a level which is unacceptable. So our patience has worn thin - we expect you to learn, not repeat behaviours that are negative.
>
> As regards 2) yes, once you have been told repeatedly on other sites (including IPS, and even Music.SE previously as well as others that mods elsewhere have informed us about) repeating the same arguments on meta is just not going to work.

I don't understand the reference to IPS or "other sites". Some questions have been downvoted, but some've been highly upvoted. Furthermore, I'm not sure how different sites, with different policies, can be fairly compared for suspending someone.

Again, as this suspension was for one answer, the other sentences feel a tad disproportionate? The meaning of "off-topic" [isn't obvious](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2872/26407), like [this](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2991/26407). When I saw my questions being closed as "off-topic", I stopped posting and [checked on Meta first](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2994/26407).

#### Objective

I'm obviously no musicologist, but I'd loathe to see other experts leave here (like on Math SE) because of disagreement with moderators.

If there's anything that I can improve, please educate me. I'm now frightened to post anyways, and will try harder not to thin anyone's  patience here.

Comment: You've answered your own question with the quote. You were not suspended for the two answers, you were suspended for a pattern of behavior explained in the quote "__Posting types of questions you have been told not to post, such as link only answers, off topic questions, and then challenging every deletion or block on meta.You have so far done the same thing on a few sites, starting off with the same minor issues but escalating over time to a level which is unacceptable.So our patience has worn thin - we expect you to learn, not repeat behaviours that are negative.__"

Comment: @Dom But I think I was suspended "for the two answers"? The suspension happened instantly after the two answers, before which I didn't post anything for a long time?

Comment: Please re-read Dom's comment and then your own comment. Dom is explaining to you the **real reason why you were suspended**. He would know, he is a moderater. He's not guessing the reason, he is telling you the actual reason. In your comment, you disagreed with him, which doesn't make sense. He is not stating an opinion, he is telling you how it is. If you want to truly understand your suspension, you will have to **accept the responses given to you**. Dom is trying to explain the suspension and instead of working to understand the explanation, you are dismissing it.

Comment: If you really want to understand something that you don't already understand, you have to read and think about the explanations that people give you, and accept those explanations as facts, and then try to change your view of the world based on those facts. Until you start doing that, it seems likely that you'll continue with the same patterns of behavior that caused your suspension. Your last paragraph of this question asks if there's anything you can do to improve. Yes. Step 1: **Accept as truth the answers given to you by moderators and change your behavior accordingly**.

Answer (score 9):

You were not suspended *just* for the two answers. You were suspended for a pattern of behavior. One of the last Mod messages you got was in response to asking the community team to respond on this issue. This was their response:

> Hello Greek - Area51 Proposal,
>
> You recently contacted us regarding this suspension and your activity
> here on Music Practice & Theory Stack Exchange.
>
> We've reviewed your activity, and response to this mod message, as
> well as activity on numerous other sites dating back to 2013 for which
> moderators have had to contact you.
>
> Through all of this, there remains a troubling pattern, described in
> the charter for suspension as ["No effort to learn and improve over time"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). You know what is expected of answers here, of questions, and of
> general behavior; I would expect that you've accumulated by this point
> a considerable amount of experience. However, you seem reluctant to
> bring that experience to bear on your contemporary contributions; this
> creates problems for other users, more work for moderators, and -
> ultimately - a bad experience for yourself.
>
> I strongly encourage you to reflect on this.
>
> You're welcome to return at the end of this 30 day period if you are
> willing to make a focused effort to improve the caliber of your posts.
>
> Regards, Stack Exchange Community Moderation Team

It should also be noted that you are still blocked on asking questions due to the pattern of questions not making sense on the site and being closed which is one of the factors that contributed to this suspension. At every point the community gave you feedback first in comments to the question then on the meta post follow up.

Answering questions is a good way to show you can participate in a positive way on this site, but they need to be good answers that actually answer the question. Your first answer was brought up on the meta and besides not really answering the question was plagiarized. Your second answer was just a link and even with the contents of the link directly in the answer, doesn't address the question asked.

[An answer in response to your first answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3022/7222) sheds light on why they don't make sense with just the copied content:

> To speak more generally, my understanding is that an answer that
> primarily consists of properly attributed and edited quotes that
> effectively answer the question should be fine.
>
> **That said, the content necessary to give the correct credit and also
> link the quoted passages together and explain how they answer the
> question is usually not trivial.**

You don't do anything to link the quotes to the questions and the quotes alone are at best tangentially related to the question especially without explanation.

So in short, [write good answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), [ask good questions](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) that are [on-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [fit the site format](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and please read and reflect on feedback from other users on the site. Do this and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks. The suspension was only for Music Practice though. So the "pattern of behavior" must have happened on this site? Again, the references to the other websites feel irrelevant.

Comment: Disregarding other sites, you've been suspended twice for low quality questions and have not listened to feedback from users which contributed to your current question ban (which is still in effect). This combined with very quickly contributing two low quality answers without listening to feedback again shows a pattern of "No effort to learn and improve over time".

Comment: But we're discussing this 30-day suspension, not that automatic question ban?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal they are related. We'd love to have you contribute both questions and answers, but you need to listen to the community's feedback. People don't get question bans from one question. There was a pattern of off-topic questions and the users of the site tried to guide you in the correct way. After the ban you were answering questions with low-quality answers and showing you didn't take the time to look at what was a good answer and instead of trying to correct it you immediately answered with another low quality answer. This is the pattern we're talking about.